# Is it possible to implement classes with modular methods?

Tags: c#, code-structure

I am trying to create an object that can call one of 3 methods in response to user input. Let's call them, `DoShape`, `DoColor`, and `DoPowerTool`. These methods exist as part of a base class and interfaces respectively:

```
Public Class PowerTool
{
...

  public virtual void DoPowerTool()
  {
  ...
  }

}

Public Interface Shape
{
  void DoShape(PowerTool p);
}

Public Interface Color
{
  void DoColor(PowerTool p);
}
```

As `DoShape` and `DoColor` require a PowerTool, the intuitive thing would be to somehow bake those methods into the PowerTool instance itself.

Unfortunately, I can't have the PowerTool class implement Shape and Color directly, since I won't know until runtime if it's a Red Square Jackahmmer or a Green Ovoid one.

I've dabbled with  C#'s delegates, and have a feeling that they might be useful in this case, but I'm not familiar enough to know how to implement them in this precise scenario, and I'm unsure if they're the right choice to give me the modular behavior I'm looking for. (I may be spoiled by Javascript in this regard, where you can simply overwrite functions on objects).

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to continue? I feel like there's probably a very simple solution that I'm overlooking in all this.

Comment: That's a lot of text and very little code. To answer the title: you might be interested in the Template Method pattern (perhaps combined with Strategy) or `partial` methods. Otherwise a code sample that demonstrates the problem at hand would be appreciated.

Comment: Your example doesn't make a lot of intuitive sense. What does a `DoShape()` method do? I have no idea. Can you show us a simplified version of your actual code?

Comment: @Blorgbeard What the method does isn't relevant (since it could do one of many different things depending on whatever implemented the interface). What **is** relevant is access to the interface method and access to the powertool members.

Comment: The simplest way to describe what I'm looking for would be "dynamic inheritance", where which implementation of an interface a class uses is determined at construction time.

Comment: That is known as the strategy pattern through dependency injection.  You would inject an implementation of the method into the constructor of the class that consumes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are referring to is the concept of a [Mixin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin).

This is where one or many implementations for an interface are defined, and then the implementations are reused for their concrete types.

This is unfortunately not really possible in .NET because the framework was desgined without that ability to use multiple inheritance.  Though, you may be able to replicate the behavior you're seeking using [extension methods](http://www.zorched.net/2008/01/03/implementing-mixins-with-c-extension-methods/) or, through dependency injection and the [strategy pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx).

If you have any further questions about the patterns, or require more applicable examples, just let me know what you're attempting to accomplish in more detail and I will do my best to help.

If I understand what you are describing, the following strategy pattern may be of benefit:

```
internal interface IPowerToolStrategy
{
    void Execute(PowerTool powerTool);
}

public class RedSquareJackhammer : IShape
{
    private readonly IPowerToolStrategy _strategy;
    internal RedSquareJackhammer(IPowerToolStrategy strategy)
    {
        _strategy = strategy;
    }

    public void DoShape(PowerTool powerTool)
    {
        _strategy.Execute(powerTool);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay. I was not familiar with the strategy pattern. It seems simple enough to implement, too (and, indeed, was something I had considered, though not by name).

Comment: I updated my response with an example for you.  If you still have trouble with it, let me know and I will revise my answer as needed.  Otherwise, please mark and answer as complete. :)

Answer (score 1):

A relatively simple way to do what you're talking about (from what I can tell) would be to simply have 3 interfaces:

```
public interface IPowerTool : IShape, IColor
{
    void Execute();
}
```

Thus, you can simply define:

```
public RedSquareJackhammer : IPowerTool
{
   void DoShape() {}
   void DoColor() {}
   void Execute() {}
}
```

Another option is to do this:

```
public PowerTool
{
     IColor color;
     IShape shape;

     public PowerTool(IColor c, IShape s) {
         color = c; share = s;
     }

     void Execute()  {
         color.DoColor();
         shape.DoShape();
     }
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
// JackHammer is derived from PowerTool, Red from IColor, Square from IShape
var redSquareJackhammer = new JackHammer(new Red(), new Square());
```

Etc.. there are many ways to skin this cat.

Comment: Regarding the first: I'd like to avoid having to define `RedSquareJackhammer`... because if I define that one, I'd have to define combinations for Blue; Yellow; and Puce, Triangle; Ovaloids; and rhomboids, and Jackhammers; powerwinches; and nailguns. (etc.) The combinatorics simply make such a solution untenable.

Comment: @RavenDreamer - I was giving you two different options.  The second version allows you to define them individually.